# How to shift focus on the side bar of VSCode programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-features

How to shift focus on the side bar of VSCode programmatically?
Is there any specific command/end-point I can make use of?

I have some custom contributes.viewsContainers, they are not getting over-ridden by another. So is there any way I can have a focus on them manually after completing a certain task?

[image]

Comment: look in the key bindings GUI for the name of your View, it shows the command to use

Comment: @rioV8, it would be like calling the same action again. I was looking if there's any command which can help me choose between the view options

Comment: what do you mean with `view options`

Comment: I have some custom viewsContainers(options on the left side bar) for a specific language. And one command is over-lapping between 2 options in the side bar. Since the command is calling both the views. I want to make sure, that it ends up with focus only one view, currently it is focusing on the second one. Now I cannot change the sequence of execution. So is there any specific command to make them in focus? Eg., Focus on Search option programmatically.

Comment: `one command is over-lapping between 2 options` ???? What does it do? How is it `calling both the views`? If you don't call the things the right way you will not get an answer. If you give code examples of what you do.....